# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, performance, api

```
this.ResponseStreamFromServer = string.Empty;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Still getting the error The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you're deliberately forcing it to use TLS 1.0 or earlier? A lot of servers are 1.2+ only nowadays. Are sure that's correct for your service?